# Collisions detected prematurely, before rectangles actually touch

Tags: collision-detection, python, pygame, aabb

I am creating a game with Pygame but my collisions are registering too soon. I'm using this code to end the game when the player collides with a pipe:

```
if player_rect.colliderect(pipe_rect): 
    pygame.QUIT
    exit()
```

It works, but it triggers too soon. If the player comes close to the pipe the game ends, even before they collide.

Here is the whole code:

```python
import pygame

pygame.init()
gravity = 0
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
jumping = False
fall = 0


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,368))

game_background = pygame.image.load("cloud.png").convert_alpha()

player = pygame.image.load("bird.png").convert_alpha()
player_rect = player.get_rect(midbottom = (170,200))

#PIPE IMAGE
pipe_1 = pygame.image.load("pipe1.png").convert_alpha()
pipe_rect = pipe_1.get_rect(midbottom = (500,600))

pipe_2 = pygame.image.load("pipe2.png").convert_alpha()
pipe2_rect = pipe_2.get_rect(midbottom = (500,200))

#set 2
pipe_3 = pygame.image.load("pipe3.png").convert_alpha()
pipe3_rect = pipe_3.get_rect(midbottom = (720,100))

pipe_4 = pygame.image.load("pipe4.png").convert_alpha()
pipe4_rect = pipe_4.get_rect(midbottom = (720,500))

#set 3
pipe_5 = pygame.image.load("pipe5.png").convert_alpha()
pipe5_rect = pipe_5.get_rect(midbottom = (920,600))

pipe_6 = pygame.image.load("pipe6.png").convert_alpha()
pipe6_rect = pipe_6.get_rect(midbottom = (920,200))

#set 4 
pipe_7 = pygame.image.load("pipe7.png").convert_alpha()
pipe7_rect = pipe_7.get_rect(midbottom = (1120,500))

pipe_8 = pygame.image.load("pipe8.png").convert_alpha()
pipe8_rect = pipe_8.get_rect(midbottom = (1120,100))

#set 5
pipe_9 = pygame.image.load("pipe9.png").convert_alpha()
pipe9_rect = pipe_9.get_rect(midbottom = (1320,200))

pipe_10 = pygame.image.load("pipe10.png").convert_alpha()
pipe10_rect = pipe_10.get_rect(midbottom = (1320,600))

#set 6
pipe_11 = pygame.image.load("pipe11.png").convert_alpha()
pipe11_rect = pipe_11.get_rect(midbottom = (1520,450 ))

pipe_12 = pygame.image.load("pipe12.png").convert_alpha()
pipe12_rect = pipe_12.get_rect(midbottom = (1520,50))

#set 7
pipe_13 = pygame.image.load("pipe13.png").convert_alpha()
pipe13_rect = pipe_13.get_rect(midbottom = (1720,550 ))

pipe_14 = pygame.image.load("pipe14.png").convert_alpha()
pipe14_rect = pipe_14.get_rect(midbottom = (1720,150))


running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False


    screen.blit(game_background,(0,0))

    keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_SPACE] and player_rect.bottom >= 0:
           jump = True
           gravity = -7
           
    gravity += 1
    player_rect.y += gravity

    
    if player_rect.bottom >= 366: player_rect.bottom = 366
    screen.blit(player,player_rect)


    #pipe 1
    screen.blit(pipe_1,pipe_rect)
    pipe_rect.x -=3
    if pipe_rect.right <= 0: pipe_rect.left = 1200

    #pipe 2
    screen.blit(pipe_2,pipe2_rect)
    pipe2_rect.x -=3
    if pipe2_rect.right <= 0: pipe2_rect.left = 1200
    
     #pipe 3
    screen.blit(pipe_3,pipe3_rect)
    pipe3_rect.x -=3
    if pipe3_rect.right <= 0: pipe3_rect.left = 1200
     #pipe 4
    screen.blit(pipe_4,pipe4_rect)
    pipe4_rect.x -=3
    if pipe4_rect.right <= 0: pipe4_rect.left = 1200
     #pipe 5
    screen.blit(pipe_5,pipe5_rect)
    pipe5_rect.x -=3
    if pipe5_rect.right <= 0: pipe5_rect.left = 1200
     #pipe 6
    screen.blit(pipe_6,pipe6_rect)
    pipe6_rect.x -=3
    if pipe6_rect.right <= 0: pipe6_rect.left = 1200
     #pipe 7
    screen.blit(pipe_7,pipe7_rect)
    pipe7_rect.x -=3
    if pipe7_rect.right <= 0: pipe7_rect.left = 1200
     #pipe 8
    screen.blit(pipe_8,pipe8_rect)
    pipe8_rect.x -=3
    if pipe8_rect.right <= 0: pipe8_rect.left = 1200
     #pipe 9
    screen.blit(pipe_9,pipe9_rect)
    pipe9_rect.x -=3
    if pipe9_rect.right <= 0: pipe9_rect.left = 1200
     #pipe 10
    screen.blit(pipe_10,pipe10_rect)
    pipe10_rect.x -=3
    if pipe10_rect.right <= 0: pipe10_rect.left = 1200
    #pipe 11
    screen.blit(pipe_11,pipe11_rect)
    pipe11_rect.x -=3
    if pipe11_rect.right <= 0: pipe11_rect.left = 1200
    #pipe 12
    screen.blit(pipe_12,pipe12_rect)
    pipe12_rect.x -=3
    if pipe12_rect.right <= 0: pipe12_rect.left = 1200
    #pipe 13
    screen.blit(pipe_13,pipe13_rect)
    pipe13_rect.x -=3
    if pipe13_rect.right <= 0: pipe13_rect.left = 1200
    #pipe 14
    screen.blit(pipe_14,pipe14_rect)
    pipe14_rect.x -=3
    if pipe14_rect.right <= 0: pipe14_rect.left = 1200


    if pipe_rect.colliderect(player_rect):
        pygame.QUIT
        exit()

   # gravity += 1
    #player_rect.y += gravity
    
    #if player_rect.bottom >= 366: player_rect.bottom = 366
    #screen.blit(player,player_rect)
  
    clock.tick(40)
    pygame.display.update()`
```

Comment: I don't have the resources to test this now, but using coordinates like this `player_rect = player.get_rect(midbottom = (170,200))` and `pipe_rect = pipe_1.get_rect(midbottom = (500,600))`, where you use `midbottom` as a reference, may offset the actual rect you test and the visual. Instead of using midbottom, try using something like topleft to see if it works. Then you should try and position your object using topleft instead before using a more sophisticated way to position your objects based on midbottom.

Answer (score 0):

#### The problem

The line `gravity += 1` will make that variable so great it'll slam your player immediately to your base `pipe_rect` prematurely ending your game.

###### To elaborate a bit more ...

Let's look at your framerate, `clook.tick(40)` which means this will loop through 40 times per second. With `gravity` set at `0`, then each loop you apply `gravity += 1`, it'll quickly become 0 to 40 to 80 to etc ... This creates the problem bug, because your `player_rect.y += gravity` line will increasingly pull the `player_rect` faster than it can resist gravity, without repeatedly pressing the spacebar.

#### Suggested Solution

###### * Adding a `if` statement to limit gravity variable

Below the line `gravity += 1`, add

```
if gravity >= 10:
    gravity = 10
```

This will give you player a constant pull to the bottom of the screen, but not to fast. The faster the player presses the spacebar key, the easier the bird can resist the gravity effect. 10 is a arbitrary number, it could be any limit you set with an `int`.